# Laravel trait crud controller with request validation and resources

Tags: laravel, crud, traits, code-reuse

I'm trying to refactor my code to be more reusable.

I created a trait CrudControllerTrait to implement the index,show,store,update,destroy methods.
But I found 2 problems:

BrandController.php

```
public function store(BrandNewRequest $request)
{
    $requestData = $request->validated();
    return new BrandResource($this->brands->store($requestData));
}
```

ProductController.php

```
public function store(ProductNewRequest $request)
{
    $requestData = $request->validated();
    return new ProductResource($this->products->store($requestData));
}
```

The trait method would be:

```
public function store(xxxxx $request)
{
    $requestData = $request->validated();
    return new xxxxxResource($this->repository()->store($requestData));
}
```

Problem1: The hint type. How can I abstract them? If I remove it shows that errror:

`"message": "Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\BrandController::store(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"`

Problem2: Return the resource. How can create the new resource? On the collection I can solve it doing this:

```
public function index()
{
    $models = $this->repository()->index();
    return $this->resource()::collection($models);
}
```

The resource is on the controller who uses the trait:

```
public function resource()
{
    return BrandResource::class;
}
```

But with single resource didn't know how to do it...

The idea is, that I have so much controllers using the same pattern: BrandController, ProductController, etc. I'd love to reuse these 5 crud methods on the same trait...

Comment: `Problem1:` try `Illuminate\Http\Request` or `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is creating an abstract method.

```
trait CrudRepositoryTrait
{
    abstract function model();

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->model()::with($this->with())->get();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return $this->model()::findOrFail($id);
    }

    public function store($data)
    {
        $request = $this->dtoRequest($data);
        return $this->model()::create($request);
    }
    
    (...)
}
```

And then, an example how to use this treat:

```
class ProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryContract
{
    use CrudRepositoryTrait;

    function model()
    {
        return Product::class;
    }
    
    (...)
}
```

By this way I could reuse a lot of code.